# how to understand the use of tryCatch in R

Tags: r

want to understand how to use tryCatch in R.

**1.** tryCatch(stop("!"), error = function(e) "An error")

> [1] "An error"

**Question**: how does the function run? stop generates the error, but what's the use of following function 'error'? what is the meaning of argument 'e'?

**2.**    show_condition <- function(code) {
        tryCatch(code,
        error = function(c) "error",
        warning = function(c) "warning",
        message = function(c) "message"
        )
        }

```
show_condition(stop("!"))
```

> [1] "error"

```
show_condition(warning("?!"))
```

> [1] "warning"

```
show_condition(message("?"))
```

> [1] "message"

**Question**: what's the meaning of 'c'? where is 'c' from? why the different return depends on the code?

Comment: Did you at least read the `?tryCatch` help page? Are you completely new to R?

Comment: The function is just an anonymous function. It *must* take an argument, because `tryCatch` will pass in the error as the argument, but you can call the argument whatever you want: `function(a)`, `function(e)`, `function(the_error_i_got)`, doesn't matter. These simple examples don't *do anything* with the error, they just return a string, but you could use a more complex function that does different things depending what the error is.

Comment: For question 2 - this is demonstrating that `tryCatch` can have different behavior for warnings, errors, and messages. I'm confused by your question: *"why the different return depends on the code?"* Different inputs lead to different outputs. This should not be a surprise.